# How can i make Select(); on each application the mouse is on screen?

Tags: c#, winforms

I did this in the top of my Form1:

```
globalKeyboardHook gkh;
```

In the Load event:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gkh = new globalKeyboardHook();
    gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.M);
    gkh.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyDown);
    gkh.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyUp);
}
```

Then in the bottom:

```
void gkh_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // e.KeyCode.ToString() is the KeyCode of the pressed key
    e.Handled = true;
    if ((e.KeyCode == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.LControlKey) || (e.KeyCode == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.RControlKey))
    {
        controlDown = true;
    }

    if (e.KeyCode == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.M && controlDown)
    {
        // Do CTRL-M action
        if (mf == null)
        {
            //mf = new MagnifierMainForm();
            mf = new MagnifierMainForm(false);
            mf.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            mf.Location = Control.MousePosition;
            //mf.Show();

            this.Select();
        }
        else if (mf.IsDisposed)
        {
            mf = new MagnifierMainForm(false);
            mf.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            mf.Location = Control.MousePosition;
            //mf.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            mf.Close();
            mf = null;
        }
    }
}

        void gkh_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            controlDown = false;
        }
```

When I'm running my application and click on the prompt command window for example then click on CTRL+M or even without clicking anything after few second I'm getting an exception:

> CallbackOnCollectedDelegate
>   A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type 'ScreenVideoRecorder!Utilities.globalKeyboardHook+keyboardHookProc::Invoke'. This may cause application crashes, corruption and data loss. When passing delegates to unmanaged code, they must be kept alive by the managed application until it is guaranteed that they will never be
>
> CallbackOnCollectedDelegate was detected
>   Message: A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type 'ScreenVideoRecorder!Utilities.globalKeyboardHook+keyboardHookProc::Invoke'. This may cause application crashes, corruption and data loss. When passing delegates to unmanaged code, they must be kept alive by the managed application until it is guaranteed that they will never be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for global keyboard hooks.
Here is a [simple C# example of usage](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook)

If you use the `globalKeyboardHook` class from the above example, you need to do 4 things:

**First** add the self-titled .cs file to your project (and since there is a bug in that code, at least in the version from 5/30/07 modify it in the following way - according to the comment from Member 4120854):

Beneath the line

```
public delegate int keyboardHookProc(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam);
```

Add this line

```
private keyboardHookProc _keyboardHookProc;
```

And change the hook method to look like this:

```
public void hook()
{
    IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
    _keyboardHookProc = new keyboardHookProc(hookProc);
    hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, _keyboardHookProc, hInstance, 0);
}
```

**Second**, in your Form class add a private member variable like this

```
globalKeyboardHook gkh = new globalKeyboardHook();
```

**Third**, on your Form_Load (or other place you want to start hooking the keys) add the key(s) you want to the HookedKeys collection Property of the gkh class and subscribe to the KeyDown and/or KeyUp events of the gkh class, like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.LControlKey);
    gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.RControlKey);
    gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.M);
    gkh.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyDown);
    gkh.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyUp);
}
```

**Fourth**, then you can do what you want in your KeyUp or KeyDown handler, setting e.Handled to true to stop propagating the key event over the system, like so:

void gkh_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
            // e.KeyCode.ToString() is the KeyCode of the released key
            e.Handled = true;
        }

```
    void gkh_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        // e.KeyCode.ToString() is the KeyCode of the pressed key
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

To do something on a specific key combination, you need to record the state of keys in a variable and upon KeyDown check if both (or all) keys are down. So for "CTRL-M" you would add a member variable

```
bool controlDown = false;
```

then you would add this code to your KeyDown event handler

```
if ((e.KeyCode == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.LControlKey) || (e.KeyCode == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.RControlKey))
{
    controlDown = true;
}

if (e.KeyCode == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.M && controlDown)
{
    // Do CTRL-M action
}
```

and in the KeyUp event handler you need to add this

```
if ((e.KeyCode == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.LControlKey) || (e.KeyCode == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.RControlKey))
{
    controlDown = false;
}
```

Comment: Bikonja ok i looked in the link and added it to my code. But i'm not sure how to make it work tried to add it to my code. Can you look in my question again i edited it ?

Comment: You're supposed to put the key handling in one (or both) of these events:  

`gkh.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyDown);  
 gkh.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyUp);`

Comment: @Bikonja - please add the example code to your answer. It'll be much more visible and properly formatted.

Comment: @ChrisF I edited my answer with example code using the class from the URL, however the answer would be too big if I added the complete code for hooks so I just used the code using the class.

Comment: I'm getting an exception. I will update my question with the code i changed.

Comment: Edited my question please look at it Bikonja

Comment: The excpetion is throw up when a new process is working for example the command prompt window then i click on it and click on the key CTRL once i click CTRL i'm getting this exception. If the new process window not opened or there is no action inside nothing happebned when clicking on CTRL+M

Comment: I'm currently not at home, but when I do get home I'll investigate this. 
I have noticed 2 error in my answer though, you need to add the Control keys to the gkh.HookedKeys collection. I believe that is not causing the exception, but will be a problem further on and you need to call unhook before closing. I will do some testing when I get home and edit my answer with my findings, if any and will leave a comment. In the meantime you can try fixing these 2 things if you understand what needs to be done from my comment.

Comment: I will try to fix it in the meanwhile. Thank you.

Comment: I could not reproduce the error on my PC, however in the linked article there is a comment that addresses this problem. I've edited my answer to include this. Please refer to the modified first part which talks about adding the globalKeyboardHook.cs file.

Apart from that, I've realized there is no need to call the unhook method since it is called in the destructor of the class already. I've edited my answer to hook for left and right control keys. Let me know if there are more problems.